# Jenkins - groovy script returned exit code 126

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I got a very simple Groovy script in Jenkins running in pipeline

For this code:

```
sh 'chmod +x gradlew'

sh './gradlew build --info'
```

I'm getting this error:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./gradlew build --info
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Pipeline with Gradle@tmp/durable-646d54ad/script.sh: line 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 126
Finished: FAILURE
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the `Jenkinsfile` block around that look like? What is `gradlew` doing at a high level?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it does not have permission to run gradlew from your error message.

`line 1: ./gradlew: Permission denied`

You can do the following:

1. SSH into the jenkins machine
2. Switch to jenkins user
   `sudo su jenkins -`
3. Check the permissions on the file gradlew using the command
   `ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline with Gradle`
4. Run the connand `./gradlew build --info` from terminal and make sure it works before you run the job again

I use declarative pipelines using groovy and it works fine. I have grails installed on the machine and jenkins user can run the command. I use:

`sh './gradlew dependencies && ./gradlew assemble && find ./ -name "*.war"'`

Please add a comment if you have any more questions...